# ActiveView::Template::Error ( uninitialized constant CustomBreadcrumbsBuilder )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using a gem called [`breadcrumbs_on_rails`](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails), and in order to use a view for this gem, I have created a class named: `CustomBreadcrumbsBuilder` in my `lib/` directory as fellows:

```
class CustomBreadcrumbsBuilder < BreadcrumbsOnRails::Breadcrumbs::Builder
  def render
    @context.render "/layouts/breadcrumbs", elements: @elements
  end
end
```

And I'm using this class in `application.html.haml` file to render the very layout in the following way:

```
%main
  = render_breadcrumbs builder: ::CustomBreadcrumbsBuilder
```

It successfully loads the file in development environment, but in production, it's producing the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant CustomBreadcrumbsBuilder):
```

I have tried the following things:

Added following to my `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/)
```

And

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

But none of thing is working. Again, it is working in development mode, but fails in production.

I'm using Rails 5.0.0, and ruby 2.2.3, and on production, I'm using Puma and Nginx to serve the requests.

Comment: Have you restarted the production rails server?

Comment: @max Sure man. More than one time.

Comment: Can you run `bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` on the production server?

Comment: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/)` and `config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"` are semantically different but should produce the same result. Both are just appending elements to an array.

Comment: @max Yes, it lists: `/home/deploy/iitan/lib`

Comment: Are you using a preloader like Spring or Zeus? Restart that, too.

Comment: @max @Raffeal: I have made it working by adding `/home/username/projectname/lib/custom_breadcrumbs_builder.rb` on top of `application.html.haml`, is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: Any specifics on how to know which one I'm using: *Spring* or *Zeus*, and how to restart one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know the exact answer, but I think `autoload_paths` are loaded after a view file is loaded, and thus Rails was unable to find a constant used in `application.html.haml` and defined in `lib/` directory. So I used the following:

```
config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/)
```

And no doubt, it is working now.

Another solution that I found is requiring the respective file directly in the view file, like I added the following line in my `application.html.haml`:

```
require '/home/arslanali/personalproject/lib/custom_breadcrumbs_builder.rb'
```

And it also worked.

Comment: [Requiring a file that defines a constant is a bad idea.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-and-require)